# Expression engine installation in wamp

Tags: wamp, expressionengine, wampserver

I'm trying to install expression engine in wamp server. Everything works fine till I fill the information page which asks about the database username and password, expressionengine licence number. Once I click the install button, then it start showing error " database error occured, Unable to connect to database server using the provided settings

Filename :" C:\wamp\www\system\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php "

line number: 124.

If I give the database user name as root and password as 'root', then it shows the above error. Please help me out. I'm new to this

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick and dirty answer.

Leave the password field empty

```
Username = root
password =
```

By default all installs of MySQL come with a single username defined `root`, and by default is has `NO` password.

However, you should really secure the `root` username as like I said, every instance of MySQL has a `root` username with no password.

Also you should, when you create a database for a project, also create a MySQL Userid/password that only has privilages on that one database, and use that in your application connection.